# Azure PowerShell Runbook Get Set Az-Disk dynamically

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

The team is trying to automate a snapshot restore, which was achieved successfully. However I am not able to figure out how to dynamically get the previous disk within the resource group; As well as set the next disk with a new name.

In the code below "AZR-001_OsDisk_7" has to set dynamically to "AZR-001_OsDisk_8" the next time it runs:

```
$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $snapshot.Location -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -CreateOption Copy
$disk = New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" -DiskName "AZR-001_OsDisk_7"
$disk1 = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" -Name "AZR-001_OsDisk_7"
```

Comment: impossible to answer your question. how would a script know its run `next time`? for example?

Comment: we are planning to schedule it for automation purpose... there is a requirement to restore a snapshot at a given time and Runbook fits perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName      
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    $account = Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
} 

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 101-Prototyping

$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" -Name "AZR-101-007-001" 

$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" -SnapshotName "SNAPSHOT-DEC-2019"

$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $snapshot.Location -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -CreateOption Copy

$disks = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" 

$attached = $disks | Where-Object ManagedBy -ne $null

foreach($disk in $attached)
{
    $arr = $disk.Name.Split('_')
     $arr[2]

}
$a = $arr[2] -as [int]
$a=$a+1
Write-Host $a

$newname = $arr[0] + "_" + $arr[1] + "_" + $a

$disknew = New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" -DiskName $newname

$disk1 = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" -Name $newname 

Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -ManagedDiskId $disk1.Id -Name $disk1.Name 

Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "ETD-RFT" -VM $vm
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a final solution, but I have a quick idea. You may use `Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName 'ResourceGroupName '` to get all the disks. And then you can get the disk name.

As you named the disk with appropriate rule, you may split the name string by `_`, then you will get a string array which contains all the parts. In this way, you will be able to get the version.

A sample:

```
$disks = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName JackVS2019

foreach($disk in $disks){
    $arr = $disk.Name.Split('_')
    Write-Host $arr[2]
}
```

The output:

```
1
```

Then you can generate the new disk name.

Comment: Will give a try, Thanks Jack

Comment: I have multiple disks and I am interested only in the attached disk...is there any way to get the attached disk ?

Comment: @user3674148 Yes; use the [`DiskState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.disk.diskstate?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Compute_Models_Disk_DiskState) property. For example: `Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName 'ETD-RTF' | Where-Object -Property 'DiskState' -EQ 'Attached'`

Comment: Or if you don't need the pipeline: `@(Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName 'ETD-RTF').DiskState -eq 'Attached'`